# CSS: Customized Jquery Alert- transparent Background

Tags: css

I am currently working with a customized jquery alert from this [SITE](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/). I am trying to achieve a gray transparent background when the alert appears but have been unsucessful. How can I get a gray transparent screen that covers the whole background behind the alertbox? Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner.ueuo.com/dropdown-menu/test1.php)

**CSS**

```
<style>
#popup_container {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 300px; /* Dialog will be no smaller than this */
    max-width: 600px; /* Dialog will wrap after this width */
    background: #FFF;
    border: solid 5px #999;
    color: #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#popup_title {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    color: #666;
    background: #CCC url(images/title.gif) top repeat-x;
    border: solid 1px #FFF;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
    cursor: default;
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 0em;
}

#popup_content {
    background: 16px 16px no-repeat url(images/info.gif);
    padding: 1em 1.75em;
    margin: 0em;
}

#popup_content.alert {
    background-image: url(images/info.gif);
}

#popup_content.confirm {
    background-image: url(images/important.gif);
}

#popup_content.prompt {
    background-image: url(images/help.gif);
}

#popup_message {
    padding-left: 48px;
}

#popup_panel {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1em 0em 0em 1em;
}

#popup_prompt {
    margin: .5em 0em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you mean you want some kind of overlay over your page to dim it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HFURu/)

The 'alertblanket' has an high z-index and overlays the entire page. Your dialog then must have a higher z-index to be on top of the 'alertblanket'

**EDIT**: You can set the color of that alert library simply by setting

```
$.alerts.overlayiOpacity = 0.5
$.alerts.overlayColor = '#AAA'
```

Or anything you like. See also the comments inside the .js file of jquery.alerts.js

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! I missed that part in the JS file